# How to replace words in a txt file in C?

Tags: c

The way I think I should write my code would be like this if i want to replace a word with 'GONE'

The question is : How would I replace a word given as an argument and replace it with the word GONE in a txt file passed through stdin

//pseduocode

```
open the file
while not EOF
  get a word from the file
  if word == 'GONE' // or argv[1]
     word = 'GONE'
end
```

I'm also confused about multiple arguments if I were to put them in, suppose.

```
./a.out hello bob bye < hello.txt
```

Which would test this file

```
Hello world and bob
I hope it's going good
but i gotta go so bye
```

and output

```
GONE world and GONE
I hope its going good
but i gotta go so GONE
```

I'm confused on how I would approach this problem in C. I think my pseduocode is correct although.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @BryanChen How would I replace a word given as an argument and replace it with the word GONE in a txt file passed through stdin

Comment: thats too broad, we won't just write code for you

Comment: @BryanChen Of course! I was just wondering if anyone could give me an idea on how to start

Comment: How you do it would depend entirely on how your program is set up. Considering you only posted pseudocode, we can't really do much; you already did what we could do for you without writing the code for you.

Comment: Your pseudocode is good in principle. But you should check each word against all arguments (with a separate function, probbaly), you should write the word to stdout and you should also keep the stuff between the words, so that "Bye, Bob!" will yield "GONE, GONE!".

Answer (score -2):

I can give you idea but the things have to be yourself. Store the text in separte string as:

```
 char sentence[] = "Hello world and bob I hope it's going \
                     good but i gotta go so bye";

 const char *to_replace = "Hello";

 const char *replacement = "GONE

 char *pos = strstr(sentence, to_replace);


while (pos != NULL) {
   //Replace the word here as you now positions

   if ( strstr(sentence, to_replace) ){
       pos = strstr(sentence, to_replace);
   }else{
      pos = 0;
   }
}
```

Now Print the buffer Replaced buffer